# Python - issue to modify a xml file using unicode latin-1

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I'm newbie python user and I'm trying to change few lines in a xml file using the DOM library.

But I'm facing with a unicode problem to do this action. 
My xml files has a line

```
<!--Selector generado a partir del proyecto de configuraciÃ³n : RigelJars_Configuration -->
```

It seems that this line isn't working with unicode 'latin-1' (in this quote: configuraciÃ³n)

```
writer.write("%s<!--%s-->%s" % (indent, self.data, newl))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The simple code below:

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_
import os,re,sys
from xml.dom.minidom import DOMImplementation, Document,parse
for dirname,subdirs,files in os.walk('/tmp/lab/resource.jar'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename == 'variableCfgSelector.xml':
            domapp=parse('/tmp/lab/resource.jar/variableCfgSelector.xml')
            print('Arquivo atualmente sendo alterado: variableCfgSelector.xml ')
            childs = [node for node in domapp.childNodes if node.nodeType == domapp.ELEMENT_NODE]
            for parent in childs:
                childs2 = [node for node in parent.childNodes if node.nodeType == domapp.ELEMENT_NODE]
                for child in childs2:
                    if child.nodeName =='environment':
                        child.firstChild.replaceWholeText('ebanking')
domapp.writexml(open('/tmp/lab/resource.jar/novo_VariableCfgSelection.xml','w'),addindent='',newl='',encoding='UTF-8')
domapp.unlink()
```

Comment: Either it's Unicode or it's Latin-1, there is no way it can be both at the same time.  The copy/paste you show looks like it's Unicode in UTF-8 encoding but you are using software configured to display Latin-1.  Showing the code which attempts to read the file could help clarify this, but this is almost certainly a duplicate of an existing question -- have you searched for similar errors?

Comment: See also [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some tips on how to ask a question about this.

Comment: Either the file is Latin-1, in which case you should specify this encoding when opening it, or you have double-encoded text where text which was already UTF-8 was erroneously encoded from Latin-1 to UTF-8 a second time. In this case, you can try to undo the conversion and end up with valid UTF-8. Without knowing the actual bytes in the file, we can only guess; but I'd put my bet on the first scenario.

Comment: XML is required to use UTF-8 so that might be part of the problem here; but again, you are not showing us how you initialize the value in `self.data` so we can't really help you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been fixed using a simple open file (as a text file) and not using parse of dom library.
My source file were unicoded with ANSI format and using the open I can define the proper unicode to work.
Thanks for all